# Magento 2 - jQuery validation remote method

Tags: magento2, jquery, validation

I'm developing a custom form with a username that require validation at server side to check if the username exists. How can I apply [the remote method of jquery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) in Magento 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add **remote** property for '**data-validate**' attribute. example:

```
<input name="email" id="email" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true, 'remote':'<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getValidateEmailAction(); ?>'}"/>
```

Here **$block->getValidateEmailAction()**; should be return link. example:

```
public function getValidateEmailAction()
{
    return $this->getUrl('stackexchange/index/validate', ['_secure' => true]);
}
```

And validate controller should be

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Validate extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
        $resultJson->setData('true');
        /*
        if(true) {
            $resultJson->setData('true');
        } else {
            $resultJson->setData('That name is already taken, try peter123 instead');
        }
        */
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

Comment: I make a controller to handle the validation. `public function execute() {
        return true;
    }` It returns `Invalid return type`

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Thanks @SohelRana for this post. Just I want to know when remote validation called on form submit or for texchange if I have text box with this validation. I want to call this validation on text change or focus out from input is there any way to do  ???

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I know when I get the response of this remote request I have to show loader till then? Is there a method for this event?

Comment: Very good ! :) @anujeet if you want to show the loader, you can add 'showLoader: true' to the remote JSON options

Comment: It seems crazy to be sending a request to a Magento server that in turn sends a request to another server.  Is there no way to poll the validation server directly?  Also, how do you do this on checkout components that have do not have .phtml templates?